# Tooltip within text without line break (css only)

Tags: html, css

I wanted to have multiple tooltips within a text on my website. I have tried to use both span and div tags to make a tooltip with CSS only and it worked for the most purt, however I have trouble positioning the tooltiptext correctly. It is supposed to show up above the hoverable word, but currently it just shows up in the line below on the left. My code:

```css
.tooltip {
position: relative;
display: inline;
text-decoration: underline dotted black;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
padding: 0.3vw;
}

.tooltiptext {
display: none;
color: white;
background-color: black;
border-radius: 0.3vw;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    <span class="tooltip">  consectetuer<span class="tooltiptext"> Some Text</span></span> 
adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
```

Are there any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you wanted something like this.

```css
p {
  padding:10px;
}

.tooltip {
position: relative;
display: inline;
text-decoration: underline dotted black;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
padding: 0.3vw;
left:50%;
top:-19px;
transform:translateX(-50%);
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}

.tooltiptext {
display: none;
color: white;
background-color: black;
border-radius: 0.3vw;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    <span class="tooltip">  consectetuer<span class="tooltiptext"> Some Text</span></span> 
adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted, but is there also a way to make the width of div containing the tooltiptext bigger than the hoverable text? I'm not sure if this is possible since .tooltiptext is the child element of .tooltip.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @Charlie It's generally not Stackoverflow etiquette to ask multiple questions within the same post, one simple reason that it would be hard to find in the comments if someone was searching for it in google. But all you would have to do is change your width value. (values can exceed 100% btw, or you just give it a defined dimension, or add more padding. Many ways) This answer solves the original question you posted and you should mark it correct if you find that it did as well.

Comment: @soulshined thanks for your helper explanations mate :)